# How can I toggle show/hide all images instead of just hiding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have a button set up to hide all images (under the class user_upload) but it only hides instead of toggling hide and show. How can I change my code so that it toggles?

```
function hidei(id) {
$('.user_upload').hide();
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: by using .toggle(), https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I've tried that but for example $('.user_upload').hide.toggle(); and $('.user_upload').toggle.hide(); don't work. Where does .toggle go?

Comment: $('.user_upload').toggle(). you don't need to chain them like that. it's just a jQuery method as shown in the api link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function hidei(id) {
$('.user_upload').toggle();
```

Comment: Okay, at first it didn't work but I tried again and now it did! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

css :

```
.user_upload {
     display : block;
 }
.no-display {
     display : none;
}
```

Js :

```
function hidei(id) {
     $('.user_upload').toggleClass('no-display');
}
```